# What is the best solution to code this view in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for some help in order to implement a view on xamarin forms. I want to now a good practice / solution in order to have this view on Windows (Desktop):

[image]

And on Android or iOS I would like to have View 1 first, and if I click on 'Movies', then navigate to View 2.

How should I do it? create two views? If creating only one view, can I do anything similar of what I want? Thanks.

Comment: View one is a [listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) and when you click one row in the listView, use [navigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) to go to View2.

Comment: I dont think you've understood the question at all... I want the screenchot for UWP desktop, and for android and iOS what you said @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: If you want the implementation of UWP instead of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, you should add the proper tag of this question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Master-Detail Page to implement such an behaviour.
Here is the link for the reference :-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

You can set the `MasterBehavior` Property to `Split` Or `SplitOnLandscape` or `SplitOnPortrait`.